How to restrict a CSS snippet to be used only for a specific property in VS Code?
`   "Set Font Settings" :
    {
        "prefix": "font-family",
        "body": "'Outfit'",
        "description": "my first font!"
    },
    "Set Font Settings 2" :
    {
        "prefix": "Young Serif",
        "body": "'Young Serif'"
    },
    "Set Font Settings 3" :
    {
        "prefix": "Work Sans",
        "body": "'Work Sans'"
    },
    "Center Div":
    {
        "prefix": "cd",
        "body":[
        "display: flex;",
        "justify-content: center;",
        "align-items: center;"]
    }`

I want to customize my CSS snippets to appear only when inserting specific properties. For example, I'd like to see the font-related snippets only when I'm inserting a font-family property and not when I'm inserting a display property. How can I achieve this level of customization?
Additionally, unlike the built-in snippets, I noticed that the formatting in my css.json file is not organized when viewed in VS Code. How can I add icons to my custom snippets, similar to the ones provided by default in VS Code?
